# mongodb group by a condition and adding up all the values in it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

simple collection:

```
[
    {
       _id: '123',
       name: 'product1',
       quantity: 10
    },{
       _id: '456',
       name: 'product2',
       quantity: 20
    },{
       _id: '789',
       name: 'product1',
       quantity: 30
    },{
       _id: '145',
       name: 'product3',
       quantity: 30
    }
]
```

what im trying to get:

```
[
    {
       _id: 'product1',
       quantity: 40
    },{
       _id:'product2',
       quantity: 20
    }
]
```

I want to filter by product1 and product2 and group by the 2 products with the total quantity.

what i tried:

```
db.CustomerOrders.aggregate([
  {
    "$match":{
      "$or":[{"name":"product1"},{"name": "product2"}
      ]}},
  {
    "$group": {_id:"$name", quantity:{$sum:"$quantity"}}
  }
  }])
```

Code doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Use `$in` in your `$match` stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      name: {
        $in: [
          "product1",
          "product2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      quantity: {
        $sum: "$quantity"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YenoP0n-Qvl)